# Error with multiple UNION query in Access

Tags: ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2010

I have an access query that accesses to mysql table through odbc connection but I'm getting this error.

> ODBC: Falló la llamada. [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.5.21] You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION
>   (SELECT `id` FROM `table2` )) UNION (SELECT `id` FRO' at line 1
>   (#1064)

I'm using this access query.

```
SELECT id FROM table1
UNION 
SELECT id FROM table2 
UNION 
SELECT id FROM table3
```

This query works in mysql and also if the tables are in access, but it doesn't work when I do the query in accesss through odbc to mysql tables.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804495/multiple-union-query-doesnt-work/15004004

Comment: And more importantly this one http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=7684 doesn't look resolved to me. I need to make an account to see the Progress log though (and I'm not making one)

Comment: It doesn't look good. As a last option, I could do a passthrough query in access. Thanks you!