# MySQL Syntax Error 1064 with Union Query in MS Access

Tags: mysql, ms-access, mariadb

Having trouble with a union statement.  Front end is MS Access, back end is MySQL (MariaDB5)

The union query works fine when the tables are located within the database.  Once I moved the tables to the MySQL database (accessed through MYODBC) I now recieve a #1064 Error at line 1.  Here is the union;

```
SELECT ModelName, "Main Floor" AS Room, MainFlrTotalCarpet As SqFt FROM 
Dec_Models
UNION SELECT ModelName, "Bedrooms Only", BedroomsTotal FROM Dec_Models
UNION SELECT ModelName, "Second Floor Hall", SecondFlrHall FROM Dec_Models;
UNION SELECT ModelName, "Loft", Loft FROM Dec_Models;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple UNION query doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804495/multiple-union-query-doesnt-work) (use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  The info in that thread is way over my head unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You have a semi-colon at the end of the next to last line. That's your syntax error.

Comment: Thanks, but that did not work.  It appears the error is at line 1.  I've been reading other posts but I'm afraid it's over my head in code.